# Как Конвертировать BufferedImage в ByteArrayOutputStream без использования ImageIO.write (для передачи через Socket)

Tags: java, socket.io

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
Rectangle area = new Rectangle((Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(robot.createScreenCapture(area),"PNG",os); //Можно ли использовать другой способ?


InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());

byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];

int read = 0; 

while( ( read = in.read( buffer ) ) > 0 ) {

    out.write( buffer, 0, read );   

}

s.close();
```

Comment: зачем нужно именно так?

Comment: а почему не пишете сразу в `out`?

Comment: @zRrr , Спасибо буду знать )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например вот так

```
int[] data = ((DataBufferInt) robot.createScreenCapture(area).getData().getDataBuffer()).getData();
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(data.length * 4);
IntBuffer intBuffer = byteBuffer.asIntBuffer();
intBuffer.put(data);

byte[] buffer = byteBuffer.array();
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ ,но выбрасывает  java.awt.image.DataBufferInt cannot be cast to java.awt.image.DataBufferByte

Comment: ImageIO.write Мне кажется вызывает утечку памяти.

Comment: При многократном выполнении кода потребление памяти больше 500mb ,возможно я ошибаюсь.

Comment: проверьте профайлером и у вас будут точные данные